# PyTorch - Freeze a specific torch.nn.Module within another torch.nn.Module containing multiple torch.nn.Modules

Tags: python, pytorch

```
    class SomeModel(torch.nn.Module)
        def __init__():
            self.state_encoder = RNNStateEncoder(
                self.goal_visual_encoder.output_dims, self._hidden_size,
            )
            self.actor = LinearActorHead(self._hidden_size, action_space.n)
            self.critic = LinearCriticHead(self._hidden_size)
            self.embedder = ResNetEmbedder(resnet=resnet_model(pretrained=True), pool=pool)
            self.train()
```

So I have this PyTorch module and I'm trying to freeze `self.embedder` and only that `nn.Module`. Is it possible to do this? Like if I do `self.embedder.eval()` after the `self.train()` will it freeze that module and none of the others?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
optimizer = optim.Adam([{'params':[ param for name, param in model.named_parameters() if 'embedder' not in name]}], lr=0.01)
```

If you want to unfreeze the frozen layer:

```py
optimizer.add_param_group({'params': model.embedder.parameters()})
```

Comment: is there a way to do it within the module I defined?